# How to use node_modules within Electron?

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, electron, typescript1.5

Using electron in combination with Angular2, Typescript and Electron I am try to find out how to use a node module package installed via npm.
The current problem is that I have to specify the location of the module like `var module = require('./node_modules/xyz/lib/xyz.js')`. But then electron does not find the dependencies of xyz, which are located within `./node_modules/xyz/node_modules/yyy` and complains `./yyy.js` can not be found.

The electron app structure

```
dist  
├── angular2.dev.js   
├── config.js  
├── index.html  
├── main.js  
├── node_modules  
├── package.json  
└── app.js
```

Comment: Turns out that I used npm to install modules, but I JSPM with Angular2 to load modules.
when installing modules with `jspm install npm:xyz`  then I can require modules in electron like require('xyz') .

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, a similar question has been asked and I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32335874/2295964) might help you!

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE:**

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32265449/2295964) has been asked and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32335874/2295964) would most probably help you here:

If you don't append the path to your app `node_modules` directory under your app root to the `NODE_PATH` variable it is not going to work. So you need to do something like this:

```
export NODE_PATH=/PATH/TO/APP/node_modules
electron /PATH/TO/APP
```

When exporting `NODE_PATH` make sure that you provide an absolute path.

---

If electron cannot find modules when you `require` them normally, it's a sign that your `package.json` doesn't contain the modules as dependency **even** if the module is already available under your `dist` directory.

So make sure that you are inside `dist` directory and use

```
npm install --save xyz
```

note the **`--save`** flag!

Answer (score 1):

> The current problem is that I have to specify the location of the module like var module = require('./node_modules/xyz/lib/xyz.js')

You should be able to do `var module = require('xyz');` If you have it locates in the relative path `./node_modules/ ....` that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't include the modules in your package.json I found it easiest to just copy all of them to node_modules in your release. It's something like `releases > ARCHITECTURE > resources > node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

According to electron's docs, set the nodeIntegration preference to true. Do this by adding

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true
}
```

to your `createWindow()` function.

Comment: This is not what you think. Node integration means you expose Node.js in the frontend, making your app especially vulnerable, security wise.