# Electron, Angular2, "fs"

Tags: typescript, angular, electron

I am very new to the topic of Angular, Javascript etc.

I try to write a (TypeScript) Angular2-Electron application which should access the file-system. Everyone just says to require the "fs" module and all is fine, but that doesn't work for me... .

If I do something like: `var fs = require('fs');`

I can see that my app tries to load that "fs" module from my app root folder:
..myapp/dist/fs net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

All my other external modules are referenced in the index.html:

```html
    <!-- build:js app/scripts/combined.js -->
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.combined.js"></script>
    <script src="boot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

And therefore I think they could be found, but "fs" belongs to node.js which is present in electron? Or have I made some big mistakes in my thoughts?

Thanks a lot,
Chris

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what happens? When you try to access  localhost in the browser (assuming you are serving to localhost) what occurs exactly?

Comment: The app work fine if i use a server (and not use any Includes for "fs"), but i compile my angular app with electron to create a desktop application. I thought that in an electron app the node-modules are already "present" but that don't seem to work. The Application try to load the "fs" module from my application folder as mentioned above. Have i to npm-install any additional depedencies to use the node-modules within my electron app?

Comment: Hhhhhmmmm, I found a question that could plausibly be related to the issue. Do the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664111/how-to-use-node-modules-within-electron-formerly-atom-shell help you at all?

Comment: Not really. I already do imports from npm-modules in my application (such as angular2) which can be retrieved by electron without any problem because i add them to my final application path. As i understand correctly "fs" belongs to node.js and should be available. Or have i to install any additional modules like "npm install 'fs' --save" to use them in my app? All Tutorials just require "fs" without any words about adding additional dependencies

Answer (score 5):

The problems seems to be that i use SystemJS in my Angular Application. SystemJS tries to load the modules from my own application.

I now have add this so my index.html which seems to work:

```
    <script>
    if (require) {
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./app/assets/js/jquery.min.js');
        window.fs = require('fs');
        window.path = require('path');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works, though it feels odd to add any module to window in order to be able to use it. It feels like there must be another solution...

Comment: @mvermand Had the same feeling and came up with IMHO a better approach. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `github` [project](https://github.com/meltedspark/electron-angular-native) I manage, which covers even more than just `Angular 2` and `electron` (it also involves native libraries).
I encountered a lot of problems that are similar to yours, in particular the issue of accessing `node.js` modules from `electron` application.
Probably it's worth to use it as a starting point, instead of trying to write everything from scratch.

As for your problem, you should use `System._nodeRequire('fs')` instead of `require('fs')` as `SystemJS` lookup mechanism is a bit different than `node`'s one.

Answer (score 2):

Let me cite the [meltedspark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769670/322984) to a similar question:

> `System.js` overrides `Node.js`'s `require` method and uses it's own resolution mechanism.

Here is my solution to this problem:

1. Create re-exports for each `Node.js` module you want to use:

   ```
   // scripts/node-re-exports/fs.ts
   declare const System: any;
   const fs = System._nodeRequire('fs');
   export = fs;

   // scripts/node-re-exports/electron.ts
   declare const System: any;
   const electron = System._nodeRequire('electron');
   export = electron;
   ```
2. Let `systemjs.config.js` know where to search for these re-exports.

   ```
   map: {
     ...

     // Re-exports of Node.js modules.
     fs: 'compiled/node-re-exports/fs.js',
     electron: 'compiled/node-re-exports/electron.js'
   }
   ```
3. Import these modules in your Angular2 components, as usual:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { clipboard } from 'electron';
   import { existsSync } from 'fs';

   @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     name = 'Angular';

     constructor() {
         const text = existsSync("c:\\boot.txt") ? "exists" : "does not exist";
         clipboard.write({ text: text });
     };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `"fs" : "@node/fs"` in the `systemjs` map you can solve the problem completely.
Then you can import the native node modules as usual:

`import {existsSync} from 'fs';`