# Using node's fs results in empty object

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I'm building a simple project with Angular 6 and Electron 4.
In my project I'd want to use fs from node but it results in an empty object when I try to output it. Here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as fs from 'fs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor() {
    console.log(fs); // empty object
  }
}
```

I've added `"browser": {"fs": false}` as suggested in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272) issue, and I've installed `@types/node` and added `"types":  ["./../node_modules/@types/node"]` in `tsconfig.app.json`.

I googled a lot to find a solution but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to use Node.js API in Angular 6.

Installed [electron-builder](https://github.com/angular-guru/electron-builder) and follwed the instruction, I can now use regular import statement.

The configuration I mentioned above helps to suppress errors like `Module 'fs' not found` and to help IDEs to recognize `fs` module

Answer (score 0):

`fs` module uses the `os` and `path` under the hood. 
According to this [answer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272#issuecomment-392777980) you need to assign false to all of them in the config object.

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
```

Comment: Just added it, but it's still empty. And if I try to use any of fs' functions, it results in error.

Comment: @MatteoMeil could you try to tell typescript during compilation where to look for your node package?` "compilerOptions": {
   ...
    "paths": {
       "fs" : "@node/fs"
    }
}`

Comment: Also, it might be the duplication of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663454/electron-angular2-fs

Comment: adding that option results in an error during build